# Sending Contact Information To External Site With AJAX

Tags: webservices, json, contact, ajax

I am working on a website that is using Salesforce for membership management purposes. Salesforce is the single repository for membership information and needs to be able to send membership information to a website when new members join the organization.

I've figured out most of this, but I've run into a problem when attempting to send my data in JSON format. Below is the code I currently have attached to a button in the Contact View:

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT('/soap/ajax/29.0/connection.js')}

sforce.connection.remoteFunction(
{
    url : "XXXXXXX",
    method : "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"
    requestData : "{id:" + {!Contact.Id} + ",fn=" + {!Contact.FirstName} + "}",
    onSuccess : function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    }
} );
```

I've tried a few ways to format the `requestData` variable, but I can't seem to figure out how to format this correctly when utilizing Salesforce merge fields. Can someone provide me with an example of how to send JSON data in this way?

Comment: This is one of the purposes of the Outbound Message workflow action, which you might also take a look at.

Comment: You can also use REST API calls in a trigger. Outbound Messaging is usually more work (development) on the remote end, and REST is more work on the local end (Apex Code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON is incorrect. I personally recommend forcing the browser to encode things correctly with JSON.stringify.

```
...
requestData: JSON.stringify( { "id": "{!Contact.Id}", "fn": "{!JSENCODE(Contact.FirstName)}" } ),
...
```

Comment: That appeared to work, but the data is placed in `Request Payload` and not in `Post`. Is that normal?